# Getting country name from list based on variable value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This code is fetching the Data from a Webpage. Then I'm setting it as variable to get the Full country name from the List.

When I set `isoCountries.CountryName` is showing undefined. **But when I set `isoCountries.US` it's showing United States.**

I want to get full country name from the list based on what I'm getting from the webpage.

This is my complete code.

```html
<h1>
<div id="data"></div></h1>
<script>
  async function test() {
    let response = await fetch("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", {
      mode: "cors",
    });

    let text = await response.text();
    country = text.split("\n").filter((el) => el.startsWith("loc"));
    let ExtractCountry = country.toString().replace('loc=', '');
    console.log(ExtractCountry);

    //Init Country List
    var isoCountries = {
        "AF" : "Afghanistan",
        "AX" : "Aland Islands",
        "AL" : "Albania",
        "DZ" : "Algeria",
        "AS" : "American Samoa",
        "AD" : "Andorra",
        "AO" : "Angola",
        "AI" : "Anguilla",
        "AQ" : "Antarctica",
        "AG" : "Antigua And Barbuda",
        "AR" : "Argentina",
        "AM" : "Armenia",
        "AW" : "Aruba",
        "AU" : "Australia",
        "AT" : "Austria",
        "AZ" : "Azerbaijan",
        "BS" : "Bahamas",
        "BH" : "Bahrain",
        "BD" : "Bangladesh",
        "BB" : "Barbados",
        "BY" : "Belarus",
        "BE" : "Belgium",
        "BZ" : "Belize",
        "BJ" : "Benin",
        "BM" : "Bermuda",
        "BT" : "Bhutan",
        "BO" : "Bolivia",
        "BA" : "Bosnia And Herzegovina",
        "BW" : "Botswana",
        "BV" : "Bouvet Island",
        "BR" : "Brazil",
        "IO" : "British Indian Ocean Territory",
        "BN" : "Brunei Darussalam",
        "BG" : "Bulgaria",
        "BF" : "Burkina Faso",
        "BI" : "Burundi",
        "KH" : "Cambodia",
        "CM" : "Cameroon",
        "CA" : "Canada",
        "CV" : "Cape Verde",
        "KY" : "Cayman Islands",
        "CF" : "Central African Republic",
        "TD" : "Chad",
        "CL" : "Chile",
        "CN" : "China",
        "CX" : "Christmas Island",
        "CC" : "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
        "CO" : "Colombia",
        "KM" : "Comoros",
        "CG" : "Congo",
        "CD" : "Congo, Democratic Republic",
        "CK" : "Cook Islands",
        "CR" : "Costa Rica",
        "CI" : "Cote D\"Ivoire",
        "HR" : "Croatia",
        "CU" : "Cuba",
        "CY" : "Cyprus",
        "CZ" : "Czech Republic",
        "DK" : "Denmark",
        "DJ" : "Djibouti",
        "DM" : "Dominica",
        "DO" : "Dominican Republic",
        "EC" : "Ecuador",
        "EG" : "Egypt",
        "SV" : "El Salvador",
        "GQ" : "Equatorial Guinea",
        "ER" : "Eritrea",
        "EE" : "Estonia",
        "ET" : "Ethiopia",
        "FK" : "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",
        "FO" : "Faroe Islands",
        "FJ" : "Fiji",
        "FI" : "Finland",
        "FR" : "France",
        "GF" : "French Guiana",
        "PF" : "French Polynesia",
        "TF" : "French Southern Territories",
        "GA" : "Gabon",
        "GM" : "Gambia",
        "GE" : "Georgia",
        "DE" : "Germany",
        "GH" : "Ghana",
        "GI" : "Gibraltar",
        "GR" : "Greece",
        "GL" : "Greenland",
        "GD" : "Grenada",
        "GP" : "Guadeloupe",
        "GU" : "Guam",
        "GT" : "Guatemala",
        "GG" : "Guernsey",
        "GN" : "Guinea",
        "GW" : "Guinea-Bissau",
        "GY" : "Guyana",
        "HT" : "Haiti",
        "HM" : "Heard Island & Mcdonald Islands",
        "VA" : "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
        "HN" : "Honduras",
        "HK" : "Hong Kong",
        "HU" : "Hungary",
        "IS" : "Iceland",
        "IN" : "India",
        "ID" : "Indonesia",
        "IR" : "Iran, Islamic Republic Of",
        "IQ" : "Iraq",
        "IE" : "Ireland",
        "IM" : "Isle Of Man",
        "IL" : "Israel",
        "IT" : "Italy",
        "JM" : "Jamaica",
        "JP" : "Japan",
        "JE" : "Jersey",
        "JO" : "Jordan",
        "KZ" : "Kazakhstan",
        "KE" : "Kenya",
        "KI" : "Kiribati",
        "KR" : "Korea",
        "KW" : "Kuwait",
        "KG" : "Kyrgyzstan",
        "LA" : "Lao People\"s Democratic Republic",
        "LV" : "Latvia",
        "LB" : "Lebanon",
        "LS" : "Lesotho",
        "LR" : "Liberia",
        "LY" : "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya",
        "LI" : "Liechtenstein",
        "LT" : "Lithuania",
        "LU" : "Luxembourg",
        "MO" : "Macao",
        "MK" : "Macedonia",
        "MG" : "Madagascar",
        "MW" : "Malawi",
        "MY" : "Malaysia",
        "MV" : "Maldives",
        "ML" : "Mali",
        "MT" : "Malta",
        "MH" : "Marshall Islands",
        "MQ" : "Martinique",
        "MR" : "Mauritania",
        "MU" : "Mauritius",
        "YT" : "Mayotte",
        "MX" : "Mexico",
        "FM" : "Micronesia, Federated States Of",
        "MD" : "Moldova",
        "MC" : "Monaco",
        "MN" : "Mongolia",
        "ME" : "Montenegro",
        "MS" : "Montserrat",
        "MA" : "Morocco",
        "MZ" : "Mozambique",
        "MM" : "Myanmar",
        "NA" : "Namibia",
        "NR" : "Nauru",
        "NP" : "Nepal",
        "NL" : "Netherlands",
        "AN" : "Netherlands Antilles",
        "NC" : "New Caledonia",
        "NZ" : "New Zealand",
        "NI" : "Nicaragua",
        "NE" : "Niger",
        "NG" : "Nigeria",
        "NU" : "Niue",
        "NF" : "Norfolk Island",
        "MP" : "Northern Mariana Islands",
        "NO" : "Norway",
        "OM" : "Oman",
        "PK" : "Pakistan",
        "PW" : "Palau",
        "PS" : "Palestinian Territory, Occupied",
        "PA" : "Panama",
        "PG" : "Papua New Guinea",
        "PY" : "Paraguay",
        "PE" : "Peru",
        "PH" : "Philippines",
        "PN" : "Pitcairn",
        "PL" : "Poland",
        "PT" : "Portugal",
        "PR" : "Puerto Rico",
        "QA" : "Qatar",
        "RE" : "Reunion",
        "RO" : "Romania",
        "RU" : "Russian Federation",
        "RW" : "Rwanda",
        "BL" : "Saint Barthelemy",
        "SH" : "Saint Helena",
        "KN" : "Saint Kitts And Nevis",
        "LC" : "Saint Lucia",
        "MF" : "Saint Martin",
        "PM" : "Saint Pierre And Miquelon",
        "VC" : "Saint Vincent And Grenadines",
        "WS" : "Samoa",
        "SM" : "San Marino",
        "ST" : "Sao Tome And Principe",
        "SA" : "Saudi Arabia",
        "SN" : "Senegal",
        "RS" : "Serbia",
        "SC" : "Seychelles",
        "SL" : "Sierra Leone",
        "SG" : "Singapore",
        "SK" : "Slovakia",
        "SI" : "Slovenia",
        "SB" : "Solomon Islands",
        "SO" : "Somalia",
        "ZA" : "South Africa",
        "GS" : "South Georgia And Sandwich Isl.",
        "ES" : "Spain",
        "LK" : "Sri Lanka",
        "SD" : "Sudan",
        "SR" : "Suriname",
        "SJ" : "Svalbard And Jan Mayen",
        "SZ" : "Swaziland",
        "SE" : "Sweden",
        "CH" : "Switzerland",
        "SY" : "Syrian Arab Republic",
        "TW" : "Taiwan",
        "TJ" : "Tajikistan",
        "TZ" : "Tanzania",
        "TH" : "Thailand",
        "TL" : "Timor-Leste",
        "TG" : "Togo",
        "TK" : "Tokelau",
        "TO" : "Tonga",
        "TT" : "Trinidad And Tobago",
        "TN" : "Tunisia",
        "TR" : "Turkey",
        "TM" : "Turkmenistan",
        "TC" : "Turks And Caicos Islands",
        "TV" : "Tuvalu",
        "UG" : "Uganda",
        "UA" : "Ukraine",
        "AE" : "United Arab Emirates",
        "GB" : "United Kingdom",
        "US" : "United States",
        "UM" : "United States Outlying Islands",
        "UY" : "Uruguay",
        "UZ" : "Uzbekistan",
        "VU" : "Vanuatu",
        "VE" : "Venezuela",
        "VN" : "Viet Nam",
        "VG" : "Virgin Islands, British",
        "VI" : "Virgin Islands, U.S.",
        "WF" : "Wallis And Futuna",
        "EH" : "Western Sahara",
        "YE" : "Yemen",
        "ZM" : "Zambia",
        "ZW" : "Zimbabwe"
    };

    var CountryName = ExtractCountry.toString();


document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '<h1>You are from <span style="color: red">'+ isoCountries.CountryName  + '</span></h1>';
  };
  test();
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  async function test() {
    let response = await fetch("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", {
      mode: "cors",
    });

    let text = await response.text();
    
    country = text.split("\n").filter((el) => el.startsWith("loc"));
    
    let ExtractCountry = country[0].toString().replace('loc=', '');
   

    //Init Country List
    var isoCountries = {
       ..
       
       document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = '<h1>You are from <span style="color: red">'+ isoCountries[ExtractCountry]  + '</span></h1>';
  };
  test();
```

Comment: You can parse the first element of result by putting [0] and get the value :=)

Comment: Thanks. Issue Solved